# How to redirect after form submit using post method (Post/Redirect/Get) with PHP

Tags: php, redirect, post, get

I have the following form:

```
<form id="frmAeroportonew" name="frmAeroportonew" method="post" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
<table>      
  <tr>
    <td><input name="iata" type="text" id="iata" value="" /></td>
    <td><input name="icao" type="text" id="icao" value="" /></td>
    <td><input name="cidade" type="text" id="cidade" value="" /></td>
    <td><input name="pais" type="text" id="pais" value="" /></td>
    <td><input name="destino" type="checkbox" id="destino" value="" /></td>
    <td><input name="alternativo" type="checkbox" id="alternativo" value="" /></td>
    <td><input name="h24" type="checkbox" id="h24" value="" /></td>
    <td><input name="btnaeroportonew" id="btnaeroportonew" type="submit" value="+" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="frmAeroportonew">
```

The idea is to submit this form, than redirect to another page (teste_redirect.php) appending the input (id=iata) value to the url (teste_redirect.php?iata=input_value).

The PHP code was made in dreamweaver cs6:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "frmAeroportonew")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tblaeroportos (iata, icao, cidade, pais, destino, alternativo, H24) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['iata'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['icao'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['cidade'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['pais'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['destino']) ? "true" : "", "defined","1","0"),
                   GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['alternativo']) ? "true" : "", "defined","1","0"),
                   GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['h24']) ? "true" : "", "defined","1","0"));

  mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $connect) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "teste_redirect.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

I apreciate all your help. Thankyou

Comment: Ok That's the idea, but what's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your insertGoto to

```
$insertGoTo = "teste_redirect.php?iata=".$_POST['iata'];
```